# Strange problem with decryption of AES using OpenSSL, Gets padded with same looking junk, Base64 padding issue

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, base64, block-cipher

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?
It works fine in my test example.. but when I use it in production model it decrypts the string but adds a padded symbol to maintain some kind of block size or something.
I didn't post my encrypt/decrypt methods as they would make this post too big, plus they work fine as my test example decrypts and encrypts properly, `ini.GetValue` is a INI retrieval method there is nothing wrong with it, plus you can see the base64 size is the same as the example code, so I believe it works fine, I never had any problems with it before without encryption when I used it, it returns a `const char*`
The problem is known as you can see the production code ciphertext has appended to it 2 null bytes which I find strange becasue both codes are pretty much identical, I'm not good at C++ so I'm probably overlooking some basic char array stuff
The encryption code I use is AES-256-CBC from OpenSSL 1.1.1

Look at my outputs to see whats wrong.

**Good looking example code:**

```
Ciphertext is:
000000: 7a e1 69 61 65 bb 74 ad 1a 68 8a ae 73 70 b6 0e  z.iae.t..h..sp..
000010: 4f c9 45 9b 44 ca e2 be e2 aa 16 14 cd b1 79 7b  O.E.D.........y{
000020: 86 a5 92 26 e6 08 3e 55 61 4e 60 03 50 f3 e4 c1  ...&..>UaN`.P...
000030: fe 5a 2c 0b df c9 1b d8 92 1f 48 75 0d f8 c2 44  .Z,.......Hu...D
Base64 (size=88):
000000: 65 75 46 70 59 57 57 37 64 4b 30 61 61 49 71 75  euFpYWW7dK0aaIqu
000010: 63 33 43 32 44 6b 2f 4a 52 5a 74 45 79 75 4b 2b  c3C2Dk/JRZtEyuK+
000020: 34 71 6f 57 46 4d 32 78 65 58 75 47 70 5a 49 6d  4qoWFM2xeXuGpZIm
000030: 35 67 67 2b 56 57 46 4f 59 41 4e 51 38 2b 54 42  5gg+VWFOYANQ8+TB
000040: 2f 6c 6f 73 43 39 2f 4a 47 39 69 53 48 30 68 31  /losC9/JG9iSH0h1
000050: 44 66 6a 43 52 41 3d 3d                          DfjCRA==
b cip len = 64
a cip len = 16
plain b = 0
plain a = 3
Decrypted text is:
wtf
Decrypted base64 is:
wtf
000000: 77 74 66 00                                      wtf.
```

**Bad production code example:**

```
Base64 (size=88)
000000: 6a 7a 48 30 46 71 73 54 45 47 4d 76 2f 67 76 59  jzH0FqsTEGMv/gvY
000010: 4d 73 34 54 2f 39 58 32 6c 37 54 31 4d 6d 56 61  Ms4T/9X2l7T1MmVa
000020: 36 45 4f 38 52 64 45 57 42 6b 65 48 71 31 31 45  6EO8RdEWBkeHq11E
000030: 39 2b 77 37 47 4e 49 4a 47 4a 71 42 55 74 54 70  9+w7GNIJGJqBUtTp
000040: 30 36 58 46 31 4d 66 45 79 44 45 71 5a 69 58 54  06XF1MfEyDEqZiXT
000050: 79 45 53 6b 65 41 3d 3d                          yESkeA==
Ciphertext is:
000000: 8f 31 f4 16 ab 13 10 63 2f fe 0b d8 32 ce 13 ff  .1.....c/...2...
000010: d5 f6 97 b4 f5 32 65 5a e8 43 bc 45 d1 16 06 47  .....2eZ.C.E...G
000020: 87 ab 5d 44 f7 ec 3b 18 d2 09 18 9a 81 52 d4 e9  ..]D..;......R..
000030: d3 a5 c5 d4 c7 c4 c8 31 2a 66 25 d3 c8 44 a4 78  .......1*f%..D.x
000040: 00 00                                            ..
b cip len = 65
a cip len = 17
crypt miss-match
plain b = 16
crypt write fail
plain a = 16
000000: 77 74 66 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 05 05 05 05 05  wtf.............
```

Here are my codes as you can see they both look very similar so I don't understand whats the problem.

**Here is a little helper function for hexdump outputs I use.**

```
void Hexdump(void* ptr, int buflen)
{
    unsigned char* buf = (unsigned char*)ptr;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < buflen; i += 16) {
        myprintf("%06x: ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            if (i + j < buflen)
                myprintf("%02x ", buf[i + j]);
            else
                myprintf("   ");
        myprintf(" ");
        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            if (i + j < buflen)
                myprintf("%c", isprint(buf[i + j]) ? buf[i + j] : '.');
        myprintf("\n");
    }
}
```

```
char* base64(const unsigned char* input, int length) {
    const auto pl = 4 * ((length + 2) / 3);
    auto output = reinterpret_cast<char*>(calloc(pl + 1, 1)); //+1 for the terminating null that EVP_EncodeBlock adds on
    const auto ol = EVP_EncodeBlock(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(output), input, length);
    if (pl != ol) { myprintf("b64 calc %d,%d\n",pl, ol); }
    return output;
}

unsigned char* decode64(const char* input, int length) {
    const auto pl = 3 * length / 4;
    auto output = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(calloc(pl + 1, 1));
    const auto ol = EVP_DecodeBlock(output, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(input), length);
    if (pl != ol) { myprintf("d64 calc %d,%d\n", pl, ol); }
    return output;
}
```

**Here is the test example that works fine.**

```
    /* enc test */
    /* Message to be encrypted */
    unsigned char* plaintext = (unsigned char*)"wtf";

    /*
     * Buffer for ciphertext. Ensure the buffer is long enough for the
     * ciphertext which may be longer than the plaintext, depending on the
     * algorithm and mode.
     */
    unsigned char* ciphertext = new unsigned char[128];

    /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
    unsigned char decryptedtext[128];

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

    /* Encrypt the plaintext */
    ciphertext_len = encrypt(plaintext, strlen((char*)plaintext), ciphertext);

    /* Do something useful with the ciphertext here */
    myprintf("Ciphertext is:\n");
    Hexdump((void*)ciphertext, ciphertext_len);
    myprintf("Base64 (size=%d):\n", strlen(base64(ciphertext, ciphertext_len)));
    Hexdump((void*)base64(ciphertext, ciphertext_len), 4 * ((ciphertext_len + 2) / 3));

    /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
    decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, decryptedtext);

    /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

    /* Show the decrypted text */
    myprintf("Decrypted text is:\n");
    myprintf("%s\n", decryptedtext);
    myprintf("Decrypted base64 is:\n");
    myprintf("%s\n", decode64(base64(decryptedtext, decryptedtext_len), 4 * ((decryptedtext_len + 2) / 3)));
    Hexdump(decode64(base64(decryptedtext, decryptedtext_len), 4 * ((decryptedtext_len + 2) / 3)), 4 * ((decryptedtext_len + 2) / 3));
    /* enc test end */
```

**Here is the bad production code:**

```
    //Decrypt the username
    const char* b64buffer = ini.GetValue("Credentials", "SavedPassword", "");
    int b64buffer_length = strlen(b64buffer);
    myprintf("Base64 (size=%d)\n", b64buffer_length);
    Hexdump((void*)b64buffer, b64buffer_length);
    int decryptedtext_len;
    int decoded_size = 3 * b64buffer_length / 4;
    unsigned char* decryptedtext = new unsigned char[decoded_size];
    //unsigned char* ciphertext = decode64(b64buffer, b64buffer_length); //had this before same problem as below line, this worked without initializing new memory I perfer to fix this back up
    unsigned char* ciphertext = new unsigned char[decoded_size];
    memcpy(ciphertext, decode64(b64buffer, b64buffer_length), decoded_size); //same problem as top line.
    myprintf("Ciphertext is:\n");
    Hexdump((void*)ciphertext, decoded_size);

    /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
    decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext, decoded_size - 1, decryptedtext);
    /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';
    Hexdump(decryptedtext, decryptedtext_len);
    strcpy(password_setting, (char*)decryptedtext); //save decrypted password back

    delete[] decryptedtext;
    delete[] ciphertext;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example that works, you get `ciphertext_len` directly from the encryption function. When you display the ciphertext, you use this length.

In the "bad production code", you calculate `decoded_size` from the length of the Base64 data. However, Base64 encoded data always has a length that is a multiple of 4. If the original data size is not a multiple of 3, then there are one or two padding characters added to the string. In both of your examples, you have two of these characters, the `'='` at the end of the Base64 data.

When calculating the length of the decrypted data, you need to account for these bytes. If there are no `'='` characters at the end of the string, use the length that you calculated (3 * N / 4). If there is one `'='` character, reduce that calculated length by 1, and if there are two `'='` characters, reduce the calculated length by 2. (There will not be 3 padding characters.)

Edit: Here is my fix: (sspoke)

```
char* base64(const unsigned char* input, int length) {
    const auto pl = 4 * ((length + 2) / 3);
    auto output = reinterpret_cast<char*>(calloc(pl + 1, 1)); //+1 for the terminating null that EVP_EncodeBlock adds on
    const auto ol = EVP_EncodeBlock(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(output), input, length);
    if (pl != ol) { printf("encode64 fail size size %d,%d\n",pl, ol); }
    return output;
}

unsigned char* decode64(const char* input, int* length) {
    //Old code generated base length sizes because it didn't take into account the '==' signs.
    const auto pl = 3 * *length / 4;
    auto output = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(calloc(pl + 1, 1));
    const auto ol = EVP_DecodeBlock(output, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(input), *length);
    if (pl != ol) { printf("decode64 fail size size %d,%d\n", pl, ol); }
    
    //Little bug fix I added to fix incorrect length's because '==' signs are not considered in the output. -sspoke
    if (*length > 3 && input[*length - 1] == '=' && input[*length - 2] == '=')
        *length = ol - 2;
    else if (*length > 2 && input[*length - 1] == '=')
        *length = ol - 1;
    else
        *length = ol;

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Interesting.. I didn't know about the `=` in base64 causing this bug, so it's only the `=`'s nothing else can cause this bug?

Comment: Also base64 output size for encryption is caluclated with `const auto pl = 4 * ((length + 2) / 3);` and base64 decoder is calculated with `const auto pl = 3 * length / 4;` and it works properly so i can't understand why is that? Look at this  https://pastebin.com/raw/z5e7n3Vr I guess OpenSSL takes care of resizing the allocated memory.

Comment: @SSpoke The encryptor rounds up, as you get 4 bytes of text for every 3 bytes (or fraction thereof) of source text. If the source lengths is not a multiple of 3 it adds 1 or 2 padding characters to fill the buffer and indicate that these characters should not be decrypted.

Comment: I guess `pl` stands for predicted length, how come `EVP_EncodeBlock` and `EVP_DecodeBlock` will always return the same size as `pl`. `EVP_EncodeBlock() returns the number of bytes encoded excluding the NUL terminator.` `EVP_DecodeBlock() returns the length of the data decoded or -1 on error.`

Comment: Thanks for helping I would of never figured this out without you.